# Why isn't this click event being fired?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

Why isn't the myMouseClick event being fired?

```
myMC:TestMC = new TestMC();
myMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myMouseClick);
addChild(myMC);

function myMouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("clicked");
}
```

As far as I can tell from the tutorials I've seen, that should work. For a moment, I thought that since I was adding the event listener to myMC, I needed to have the event function inside the myMC class, but that didn't work. Just gave an error about accessing an undefined property.

If it helps any, TestMC is a seperate .as file that extends movie clip.

I'm just trying to make it so when the movie clip itself is clicked, it does something. The movie clip itself will be following the mouse.

Comment: The bit of code you pasted works for me (with the exception of missing "var" at the front of the first line). Does the movieclip visually appear on the stage? Could there be something inside the TestMC class that is suppressing the mouse event?

Comment: It appears on the stage, but clicking it does nothing. The trace never executes. testMC extends MovieClip and has one variable. In its constructor, I'm adding an event listener for when it enters the frame, so it has it's own update loop.

Comment: Interesting. I commented out the event listeners above it that were added to the stage (Mouse_Move and Enter_Frame), and the click went through, but only once. I couldn't click on it again. What could be causing this?

Comment: Never mind, fixed it. The object I was trying to click was made up on vertical lines. Apparently the whole movie clip isn't a collider... just the pixels in it.

Answer (score 0):

The object I was trying to click was made up on vertical lines. Apparently the whole movie clip isn't a collider... just the pixels in it, so when I was clicking, I wouldn't hitting enough of it. Changing it to a box worked. I could probably nest it if I wanted the same design, but that's fine.

Comment: Yes. A DisplayObject's bounding box is not its hit box. The hit box is the pixels being displayed. Easy way around this is to just create a transparent gradient that is the full size of the DisplayObject. This will then be your hit area rather than just your content.